# Error when creating a survey table in survey package R

Tags: r

I am new to programming and currently using R.
I am trying to create a survey table that takes into consideration the survey design.
I created my `svydesign` variable, which works, but I am now struggling with the `svytable` function. Please see below my code:

```r
svytable(
  ~ C_HAZ_GR + C_SEX2,
  design = DHS_2015_ZBW,
  data = fin_df,
  na.action = na.exclude
)
```

And I get the following error:

> no applicable method for 'svytable' applied to an object of class "c('spec_tbl_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

I get the same error if I try to use a very simple table, such as:

```r
svytable(~C_HAZ_GR, design = DHS_2015_ZBW)
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: It's really hard to do more than guess without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862)—we don't have your data or your survey design. Do you have any errors when you run the package examples?

Comment: Hello, this is my survey design:                                                                   
   DHSdesign<-svydesign(id= ~fin_df$PSU, 
                     strata= ~fin_df$STRATA, 
                     weights= ~fin_df$PERWEIGHT,
                     data=fin_df)  I dont know if this helps. How can I share my data with you?

Comment: Read the link in my comment, which gives examples of ways to make a question reproducible, and [edit] the question to include that additional code